# Add dialog parameter in mask from script

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm using Matlab R2011a and I'm trying to add a dialog parameter to a mask from a command line. I saw in the R2013 simulink documentation that it is possible to do this in the new version :

```
p = Simulink.Mask.get(baseComponent);
p.addParameter('Type', 'popup', ...
               'TypeOptions', {'Default values' 'Variable names' 'User defined'}, ...
               'Prompt', 'Default values', ...
               'Name', 'setDefault')
```

I'm unable to use these commands in R2011a. What command should I use to do the exact same thing in Matlab R2011a?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely possible in older versions of Matlab, without using the object interface, instead you must assemble the parameter attributes and then use `set_param`.  It needs to be done in a certain order:

```
set_param(gcb,'MaskPrompts',maskPrompt);
set_param(gcb,'MaskStyles',maskStyles);
set_param(gcb,'MaskTunableValues',maskTunVals);
set_param(gcb,'MaskCallbacks',maskCallbacks);
set_param(gcb,'MaskEnables',maskEnables);
set_param(gcb,'MaskVariables',maskVar);
set_param(gcb,'Maskvalues',maskvalue);
```

Some attributes can be a cell array, others must be a long string that specifies each value.  You should be able to quickly discover which is which by doing a `get_param` on a block that currently has parameters. HTH!

Comment: Ok, I know how to use these commands, but I need the new dialog parameter to be added at the start.